# How to increase the stack size while running a jar file by double-clicking

Tags: java

I know that I can modify the stack size while running a jar file using command prompt, with the `-Xss<size>` parameter. However, is there any way of doing that when I double-click the jar file to run it? I mean, I want the jar file to run with an increased stack size whenever I double-click it. Do I have to modify the manifest file?

Comment: How did you get as far as asking "do I have to modify the manifest file" without Googling "Java manifest file stack size"?

Comment: @ Soham Bhattacharya : There is no way to you can do that.  You need a custom launcher for it.

Comment: @ djechlin: I did Google things like 'adding parameters to a manifest file', 'increasing stack size while running a jar file', etc. , but to little avail. Thanks for mentioning 'Java manifest file stack size'. Will look that up.

Comment: How is this supposed to be a duplicate? The answers given in the dupe do not address `.jar` files as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a batch file and add an association for type .jar.  The, when you right-click the jar you get a choice of how to launch. Add whatever params you want in the batch file.  You can even make it the default launcher.

[image]

To get you started, here is an example of one of my simpler batch files:

```
call setjdk jre7_64bit
call java -jar %1
pause
```

Comment: Danke! Works perfectly!

Comment: Just for the note, I did not require 'call setjdk jre7_32bit'. Any idea why?

Comment: @SohamBhattacharya I have multiple JVMs installed.  That command selects the particular JVM to use.  Without that command the default JVM is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the default properties of the JVM. You can do it by setting the environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS on windows I think (to be confirmed)

Comment: I don't want to increase my default stack size. Just the stack size while running a particular jar file. Thanks anyway.